# Updating a Couch Document

Tags: couchdb

Assuming i have an existing couchdb JSON document hosted on the server. And i want to add some data to that document using PUT how can i do that ? Lets say the document has the following data already :

```
"users : [{"name" : "John","lastname" : doe"}]
```

I want to add another user:

```
"users : [{"name" : "jane","lastname" : doe"}]
```

Can this be done with `curl` and `PUT` ? assuming i get the doc id of the document from the server and do something like :

```
curl -X PUT -d $new http://127.0.0.1:5984/database/$documentid"
```

I tried the above which failed. So was wondering if there is a way to update couchdb documents by adding new stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "[update handler functions](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html?highlight=update%20functions#update-functions)" to do partial updates of documents.